# "URL Does Not Exist" when linked to a Published Community Builder page

Tags: community, community-builder, landing-page

So this issue has been plaguing my community for days now.

I have a Default Home page (which works; I can edit it and my users can view it once they log in),

However, I created a new Community Builder page and put a link on the home page to this page, but whenever the user clicks on the link they're taken to a "URL DOES NOT EXIST" page:

[image]

The thing is the community builder says this page is published.

[image]

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: can you elaborate on "put a link on the home page to this page"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you check how your URL is constructed.If its a template based community like Napili your URL should be : domainname/communityname/s/pagename. When you click the link if its not getting constructed in this format then you will definitely get this error('URL does not exist').

When you click the link on the home you should do a relative URL re-direct.(../pagename)

Comment: It was this! Thanks! I kept leaving out a /s/!